# Is there a program like GITLAB written in PHP?

Tags: php, gitlab

I'm looking for a program to run on my company's intranet to help sort out projects. GitHub it out of the question because I'm not going to pay money for private repos, but I love the way GitHub looks.

GITLAB is also nice and I would have chosen it except my servers are running PHP not Ruby. Is there a solution?

Comment: You can use the default web interface Gitweb or a better looking similar to GitHub interface, called GitList and written in PHP: https://github.com/klaussilveira/gitlist/

Answer (score 4):

There are some projects for PHP but all are not that actively developed compared to GitLab

- gitphp - http://gitphp.org/projects/gitphp/wiki ... kind-of dislike that the project's website is based on Redmine ... 18 contributors - only 1 seems to be active http://www.ohloh.net/p/gitphp/contributors
- mtrack - http://mtrack.wezfurlong.org/features.html ... 9 contributors - 2 active http://www.ohloh.net/p/mtrack/contributors
- Redmine-Php seems to be dead (homepage is down ... git-repo not updated since 1 year)
- traq also seems interesting ... http://traq.io/

And of course, many more I don't know of :)

Feel free to search for similar projects on https://www.ohloh.net for trac, redmine, gitlab and other known systems.

In my opinion mtrack seems like the most promising as it provides functions like forking projects in the UI.

Answer (score 3):

use https://bitbucket.org/ i use it for all my private repositories, it is reliable. also you can host git and svn projects.

Answer (score 3):

The alternatives to GitLab are [listed here](http://alternativeto.net/software/gitlab/?platform=linux).

Regarding PHP, the only one would be [Redmine-Php](https://github.com/saadullahsaeed/redmine-php), but with very little development activity on it.
So there doesn't seem to be any viable PHP "GitLab-like".

- [Trac uses python](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/DevelopmentEnvironmentSetup).
- [Redmine uses ruby on rail](http://www.redmine.org/)
- [GitLab](http://gitlabhq.com/) itself uses ruby.

Answer (score 2):

maybe [phabricator](http://www.phabricator.com/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: no, it does not support managing repositories.